# Grub2 menu doesn't appear

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have installed windows 10 on my pc and I had Ubuntu before I install that. But after windows installation I couldn't boot Ubuntu since grub2 menu doesn't appear and it will directly boot to Windows. I need a way to get grub2 menu.